# Checking function return value feels like inventing protocol. How to avoid the awkwardness?

Tags: function, error-handling, return-value, subroutine, control-flow

By convention, 0 means success and other values mean failure. But for three or more kinds of results, it becomes inconvenient.

E.g.

`SUCCESS = 0, DO_NOTHING = -1, OTHER_ERROR = 1`

or

`SUCCESS = 0, NOT_FOUND = 1, DUPLICATE = 2, TIMEOUT = 3, EMPTY = 4, OTHER_ERR = 5`

Needless to say, ugly code like this should be avoided:

```
switch(doX()){
case 0:
    //do Y
    break;
case 1:
    //show a message and do Z
    break;
case 2:
    //write error log and report the error
    break;
}
```

Several ways to approach the issue:

1) Use enumeration/constant code values (invent a protocol).

This is like many real-world software projects. So each library/module needs its own protocol.

Sometimes functions in a module differ drastically in result semantics, so I end up inventing protocol for each function. (For function `doX`, I declare `const int doX_RESULT_A = 1, doX_RESULT_B = 2, doX_RESULT_C = 3`.)

2) Don't write function with three or more kinds of results in the first place. Rewrite the function as two or more separate functions.

This can be bad for separation of concerns. It may complicate your code. Not very helpful.

3) Pass anonymous functions (lambda)

```
doX(
    normal_arguments,
    []{
        //execute after success
    },
    []{
        //execute after failure
    }
);//returning after calling callback may take advantage of tail call optimization
```

There might be overhead. And local anonymous function is not always supported. (Fortunately, the syntax became widely supported in modern programming languages.)

4) Rewrite the function as Macro like `#define DO_X(parameters, caseSuccess, caseFailure) { ... }`

Call it like:

```
DO_X(normal_arguments,{
    //execute after success
},{
    //execute after failure
})
```

But performance can be worse than normal nested function calls. And it causes many other problems. Besides, many languages don't have macro.

5) Pass labels-as-values

```
goto *doX(normal_arguments, &&success, &&failure);
success:
    //execute after success
failure:
    //execute after failure
```

It's non-standard, and only supported in C and C++.

6) Instead of nesting function calls, use a global function pointer to store the next callee.

The code is like `for(;;){ callee(); }`. (The pointer `callee` is modified in each `callee()`.) But breaking the loop requires an exception or longjmp.

Besides, passing arguments is not convenient and performance can be worse.

7) Throw different exceptions and catch them for control flow. (including longjmp)

Throwing Exception is expensive and people consider it bad.

8) Returning string value like "cancel" and "other_error"

Check string return value is not very convenient in some languages.

---

Form time to time, I still cannot come to a conclusion and the issue makes me hesitate, though there is nothing new about it.

In the end, is there a best way to approach it? Why can't I solve this problem systematically?

Comment: Having multiple different return value *is* a protocol. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @Bergi Declaring the constants which pollute namespace and then using them in switch statement for checking return value are so much hassle. Besides, there is performance penalty in checking return value.

Comment: @Bergi So sometimes I prefer callback hell. Though callback hell has its own problems.

Comment: "polluting the namespace" depends a lot on the programming language, which you did not yet specify. But really having a return *value* is the go-to solution that makes it easy to write composable functions, and you can still implement the other syntaxes on top of it. Whether you need to implement the abstract return values as integer enums again depends on your language.